# How do I select from a table and delete all other non-selected entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-drop

Is there an elegant way to delete all non-selected entries from a table after selecting from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `DELETE` and not `DROP`. `DROP` can only erase an entire object (e.g., TABLE). If you aren't worried about performance, you can have something like

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mytable_key NOT IN 
  (SELECT mytable_key FROM mytable WHERE some_or_another_condition);
```

Many DBs allow a `JOIN`-type syntax that will probably perform better if you have to do this on a frequent basis.

Comment: Would MYSQL have such a function?

Comment: I don't think that will work in mysql due to the restriction on deleting and selecting from the same table in the same statement (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/delete.html). But you can work around it by doing a nested subselect (see example at the bottom of http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5037):

Comment: @davek You appear to be correct: apparently in MySQL it is necessary to alias the subquery. That's substandard. Note to OP: That second link of davek shows the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Scary and generic statement... but this will do from whatever table... I wouldn't think you would actually do to a production table though...

delete from SomeTable where NOT (some condition)